# Loop through images and set background on hover in wix velo

Tags: javascript, velo

I'm trying to set the background image of a wix strip to change images by looping through an array when it is hovered on. I do not see any errors being thrown in the editor, however it is still not working. This is my current code.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
var image1 = "https://workful.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Women-in-Small-Business.jpg";

var image2 = "https://data.europa.eu/sites/default/files/news/2020-25-3.jpg";

var image3 = "https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Fstartswithabang%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F10%2FTiny_bit_of_U.jpg";


var Background_imagez = [image1,image2,image3];

let playing = false;
let current = 0;

 const run = () => {
setTimeout(() => {
    $w('#columnStrip1').background.src = Background_imagez[current];
    if (current < Background_imagez.length) {
        current++;
    } else { repeat() }
   }, 500);
   }

  const repeat = () => {
    current = 0;
      run();
     }

 $w('#text59').onMouseIn(() => {
    playing = true;
    while (playing) { run() }
    })

    $w('#columnStrip1').onMouseOut(() => {
    playing = false;
    current = 0;
    $w('#columnStrip1').background.src = 
     'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2831956.png' || 
    'https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1593005510329-8a4035a7238f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80'; // Default    
    })


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `for` loops incorrectly.

`for` loops do not return a value so you cannot assign them to a variable. You also missed out adding `for` prior to assigning `let index = 0`

```js
for (let index = 0; index < Background_imagez.length; index++) {
    $w('#columnStrip1').background.src = Background_imagez[index];
}
```

I am not sure if the above would actually show anything other than the last image as it will probably loop through too fast for anyone to see but it should fix your `Identifier expected` error.

Please refer to the documentation on [for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) on MDN

Comment: ok, I updated my question to contain my current code! thanks for the documentation.  it still don't seem to work and I am not seeing any errors in my editor.